# Remove single quotes and last comma in jquery string using Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have a data

```
'abc','def','ghi',
```

I want to remove the single quote on all character and want to remove only the last comma, example like below

```
abc,def,ghi
```

How would i achieve that using regex for javascript?

I tried using this regex

```
.replace(^\'|,\s*$,"");
```

But seems like it is only removing the first quote as shown below

```
abc','def','ghi',
```

I am not very good in regex, i appreciate any help that i can get. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
.replace(/\'|,$/g, "");
```

the `^` at the beggining made the regexp to only match the quote at the beggining of the string, also you have to add the `g` to keep looking after the first match

Comment: Lets say if i want to remove comma in front and all single quotes, which regex should i use?
`,'abc','def','ghi'`
to
`abc,def,ghi`

Comment: You add a `^,` to capture the first comma: `.replace(/^,|\'|,$/g, "");`

Comment: Thank you so much! You're my saviour!

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way, use the `$` operator

```
.replace(/'|,$/g, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check `replace(/'|(,)$/g," ")` and it should work.

Comment: This is working as well, but it is more complicated than the one from izambl